# Python - Parsing all XML files in a folder to CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, export-to-csv

I just started learning python so this might be a very basic question but here's where I'm stuck.

I'm trying to parse ALL XML files in a given folder and outputting CSV files, with the same filename as the original XML files. I've tested with single files and it works perfectly but the issue I'm having is with performing the same for all of them and having that running on a loop as it would be a perpetual script.

Here my code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as Eltree
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:/python_test'
filenames = []


for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    print(fullname)
    filenames.append(fullname)


cols = ["serviceName", "startDate", "endDate"]
rows = []

for filename in filenames:
    xmlparse = Eltree.parse(filename)
    root = xmlparse.getroot()
    csvoutput=[]


for fixed in root.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}channel'):

    channel = fixed.find("channelName").text


for dyn in root.iter('programInformation'):
    
    start = dyn.find("publishedStartTime").text
    end = dyn.find("endTime").text

    rows.append({"serviceName": channel, "startDate": start, "endDate": end})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df.to_csv(csvoutput)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
C:/python_test\1.xml
C:/python_test\2.xml
C:/python_test\3.xml
C:/python_test\4.xml
C:/python_test\5.xml
C:/python_test\6.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 49, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ragehol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3466, in to_csv
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "C:\Users\ragehol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1105, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\ragehol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 237, in save
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\ragehol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 609, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\ragehol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 396, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Any kind of suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is you bug:

`csvoutput=[]` is defined as a `list`. Later on you pass it as argument to `df.to_csv(csvoutput)`. So you are passing a `list` to a method that looks for a file path.